# Vector Nav 200 integration with Pixhawk

Tags: imu

I was aiming to integrate VN200 with PX2.4.8. So I was reading the online documentation of PX4 which stated, VN200 is already available. The Driver is present in Github repo. However, I am failing to find the setup code.
I read through this"https://ardupilot.org/plane/docs/parameters.html#eahrs-type" to see the parameters, and this for further clarification on driver "https://docs.px4.io/main/en/modules/modules_driver_ins.html". this page includes a link for setup that doesn't work.
"https://docs.px4.io/master/en/sensor/vectornav.html".

I am unable to access this as it says 404 not found. Any solution?

My aim is to use Vn200 as default IMU over pixhawks IMU. I can not find the necessary guide or documentation to implement that.